# Why VisionOS has no MapKit Annotation tapping interaction support?

Tags: ios, swiftui, mapkit, visionos

**Update: For preventing to give wrong information about the context, please read the answer that I added above.**

I'm trying to adapt my current production ready iOS/iPadOS 17 app to visionOS and I'm trying it directly running the app for the Apple Vision Pro (Designed for iPad) target.

I have a bottom sheet to show Map items detail by tapping on the Map Annotations. The bottom sheet is opening properly with a normal Button action but it's not opening by Annotation which wrapped a Button action. It pops up as expected on iOS/iPadOS but on VisionOS it doesn't.

```
struct SomeAnnotation: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: UUID
    let title: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let text: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: SomeAnnotation, rhs: SomeAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position: MapCameraPosition = .automatic
    @State var selected: SomeAnnotation?
    @State private var planBottomSheet: Bool = false
    
    let annotations: [SomeAnnotation] = [
        SomeAnnotation(
            id: UUID(),
            title: "Location 1",
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 43.64191952505181,
                longitude: -79.38918661813415
            ),
            text: "Text 1"
        ),
        SomeAnnotation(
            id: UUID(),
            title: "Location 2",
            coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: 43.64083254041681,
                longitude: -79.3859357809321
            ),
            text: "Text 2"
        )
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(position: $position) {
            ForEach(annotations, id: \.self) { result in
                Annotation(result.title!, coordinate: result.coordinate) {
                    Button(action: {
                        selected = (selected == result ? nil : result)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "bolt.car.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundStyle(.red)
                            .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                            .background(.white)
                            .clipShape(.circle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $planBottomSheet) {
            SomeView(bottomSheet: $planBottomSheet) // just for an example
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @Binding var bottomSheet: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("This is some view")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

But, it works for the following button action as expected and for the reproduce the problem and see the following code button action works you copy/paste the code below to above one's body;

```
var routePlannerButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            planBottomSheet = true
            if mapViewModel.planDetentCondition {
                mapViewModel.planBottomSheetDetent = .large
            } else {
                mapViewModel.planBottomSheetDetent = .medium
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "point.bottomleft.forward.to.arrowtriangle.uturn.scurvepath.fill")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .padding()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $planBottomSheet) {
            RoutePlannerView(
                planBottomSheetDetent: $mapViewModel.planBottomSheetDetent,
                planBottomSheet: $planBottomSheet,
                isNavigating: $isNavigating,
                showingDetails: $showingRouteDetails
            )
            .presentationDetents(
                [mapViewModel.planBottomSheetDetent, .large, .medium],
                selection: $mapViewModel.planBottomSheetDetent
            )
            .presentationContentInteraction(.resizes)
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .medium))
            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note, `@State ...` should be used for **value types**, eg String, Int, .... and `struct`.
So you could try `struct SomeAnnotation...` or you can use `@Observable class SomeAnnotation ...`, 
See the docs here [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state)

Comment: You're right. But, that's not the main reason. I found that in Mapbox sdk docs. and I guess the reason why that annotations don't pops up.

```All the interactive UI elements on Vision OS are expected to have visual feedback when the user looks at them. Currently, this effect is only available for native views and can be applied with hoverEffect. Mapbox Map renders most of the map content in Metal, which means the hover won’t be available for map symbols, lines, polygons, and others. However, you can use view annotations to place interactive elements onto the map.```

Comment: I would submit this as a big report in Feedback Assistant

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem wasn't related to VisionOS SwiftUI iOS 17 Map Annotation support but the problem that I saw was that I was not doing anything to trigger bottomSheet in the annotation. My Map() should also keep track of the selection.  With a selection: plus a .tag on the annotation, I didn't need a button in the annotation label at all. Also, I was looping over two different types in map, and the $selection was looking for a single type. So the tags for the chargers are ignored.